# Excel: Performing a mass data pull from one sheet to another, but only certain columns

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a built-in way to accomplish something like this, or a clever way with VBA, etc?

For example, say I am on Sheet1. I want to be able to say "Okay, start pasting data on Sheet 1 starting at row (whatever), from this source sheet, but only from these columns".

So for example on Sheet 1, we have Column A, Column B, and Column C containing "Name, ID, Type" data from Sheet 1, from row 5 onward -- the data for which comes from Sheet2, Columns D, H, K (and that data starts on row 7).

Right now I am pretty much just doing a raw VBA iteration by rows and copying over values, but I have to do this type of procedure for many different data sources and columns, so it's getting messy and I don't know if there's a smarter way to do this.

Comment: Would help to show your existing code.  Also "from this destination sheet" - do you mean "from this **source** sheet" ?

Comment: Most likely you can take your existing code and generalize it, which is why it's useful to post it (but you don't need to post *all* of it, just enough for someone to get the idea of what you're doing)

Comment: First thing first: you guys need to re-organize how data is handled in your spreadsheets. Working with bad input data only leads to complications.

If there's no discipline or structure in the inputs, there won't be in the future... which will lead to scenarios where

1. The solution/macro has been created, but then someone adds a row to a sheet and it screws up your entire macro.

I'll post the code later this week if someone hasn't answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not copy whole ranges instead of single cells (`1000` is just an example):

```
Sub DoTheJob()
    Copy Sheet2.Range("D7"), Sheet1.Range("A5"), 1000, 1
    Copy Sheet2.Range("H7"), Sheet1.Range("B5"), 1000, 1
    Copy Sheet2.Range("K7"), Sheet1.Range("C5"), 1000, 1
End Sub

Sub Copy(from As Range, toRange As Range, rows As Integer, columns As Integer)
    Range(from, from.Offset(rows, columns)).Copy Destination:=toRange
End Sub
```

**Update:**
For copying between different workbooks use something like this:

```
Set sheetFrom = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sheetTo = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
Copy sheetFrom.Range("D7"), sheetTo.Range("A5"), 1000, 1
```

(Of course both workbooks have to be opened before)